# Defining foreign key associations correctly in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have been working on my models for my ERD in node / postgres / sequelize and have been loosely defining my associations as I have been going along. In the case of the below am I correct in believing that I only have to define the foreign keys on the one table? In the example below I have two fields that I want to pull the associated data from other tables when I query them. Am I going about this the right way.

I have previously defined foreign keys in PhpMyAdmin and only done them on the one table. I have yet to pull the correct data in my Postman queries and have only returned the int values of the primary table. Is this dependent on me having my foreign keys set-up correctly? Or do I need to specify something in my controller API?

```
articleID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                allowNull: false
            },
            articleTitle: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            articleContent: {
                    type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            articlePhotos: {
                data: Sequelize.Buffer,
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            articleAuthor: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            articleType: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            }},
            {
                timestamps: false
            }, {});
            article.associate = function(models){
                article.articleType.belongsTo(models.article, {
                    foreignKey: {name: 'articleTypeID', as: 'articleType'}})
                article.articleAuthor.belongsTo(models.userLogin, {
                    foreignKey: {name: 'userID', as: 'userAuthor'}})
            };
```